Editing XML Values In PowerShell
This one gets me every time, and it seems each time I do it, it's a slightly different scenario so looking back at my old stuff isn't helping me make it work.  I have an XML file formatted as
<Configuration>  
  <StudySearchLayout>
    <Column Id="LastName" Hidden="n" />
    <Column Id="FirstName" Hidden="n" />
    <Column Id="Gender" Hidden="y" />
  </StudySearchLayout>
</Configuration>

My main objective is to hidden="n" on all columns.  I tried this:
$File = ".\File.xml"

[xml]$XML = gc $File

$columns = $XML.Configuration.StudySearchLayout.Column

ForEach($column in $columns){

    $column.hidden = "n"
    
}

$XML.Save($File)

If I go back and run $columns.hidden, PowerShell shows the value I'm looking for, but it doesn't appear to actually save anything in the file...  Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?


do not use alias on scripts. Have you tried to run it with the full cmdlets? Also it doe work perfectly on my system, both on 5.1 and 7.4


Use a full path for $XML.Save().

You could use SelectNodes here where the Hidden attribute is not equal to n and then, for each node, set the attribute with the new value:
$File = Convert-Path ".\File.xml"
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load($File)
$xml.SelectNodes("//*[@Hidden != 'n']") | ForEach-Object SetAttribute('Hidden', 'n')
$xml.Save($File)

As aside, always avoid using relative paths when calling .NET methods, use Convert-Path as shown above. See this Q&A for more details.

My spidey-sense says the "aside" in your answer is the actual issue. The OP's original code seems to update the in-memory xml fine but they say "it doesn't appear to actually save anything" - it probably does, just to a different file because of the different relative directory roots in PowerShell and dotnet :-).
